# Taking a string representation of a large integer and converting it to a byte array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, endianness, bitcoin

Basically, my problem is two-fold, and refers pretty specifically to the Bitcoin RPC. I am writing a miner in Java for Litecoin (a spinoff of BTC) and need to take a string that looks like:

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffff0f0000
```

Convert it to look like

```
00000fffff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

(Which I believe is switching from little endian to big endian)

I then need to turn that string into a byte array --

I've looked at the Hex class from org.apache, String.toByte(), and a piece of code that looks like:

```
public static byte[] toByta(char[] data) {
    if (data == null) return null;
    // ----------
    byte[] byts = new byte[data.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        System.arraycopy(toByta(data[i]), 0, byts, i * 2, 2);
    return byts;
}
```

So essentially: What is the best way, in Java to change endianness? And what is the best way to take a string representation of a number and convert it to a byte array to be hashed?

EDIT: I had the wrong result after changing the endian.

Comment: Probably the most efficient would be to skip the endian conversion and just create the byte array directly from the little-endian char array, two char bytes at a time.  It's easy to write your own hex-char-to-binary-byte converter, so you can avoid the arrayCopy kludge.

Comment: But note that the endian conversion you demonstrated was wrong.  The first five hex digits should be zero.

Comment: Note that your new byte array should be HALF the length of the char array, not twice its length.

Comment: I changed the endian conversion to be correct. Why would it be half the length of the char array? I thought chars were one byte each?

Comment: @D.vanderbleek Java uses UTF-16 internally

Comment: There is one char per hex digit, two hex digits per binary byte.  (Doesn't really matter whether chars are one byte or two -- the length of your byte array in bytes will be half the length of your char array in chars.)

Answer (score 2):

1. Integer and BigInteger both have toString methods taking a radix, so
   you can get the hex String.
2. You can make a StringBuffer from that
   String and call reverse().
3. You then convert back to a String using
   toString(), then get the bytes via getBytes();

Don't know if this is "best" but it requires little work on your part.

If you need better speed, call getBytes() on the original wrong direction hex string (from step 1) and reverse it in place using a for loop.  e.g.

```
for (int i=0; i<bytes.length/2; i++) {
   byte temp = bytes[i];
   bytes[i] = bytes[bytes.length - i];
   bytes[bytes.length - i] = temp;
}
```